# How do I change integration order?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I need to bound (or calculate in a closed form) this integral:
$$\int_{R}^{\infty}dz\int_{a-bz}^{\infty}dy\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} e^{-z}$$ as a function of $R,a,b$. The result can be expressed in terms of: 
$$ Q(x) = \int_x^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dt$$

Comment: Is your first formula correct, i.e. shouldn't it be $-{y^2}$. You can proceed further by partial integration wrt $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the integration order, it is useful to draw the integration domain.
On the first figure, the domain is bounded by $y=R$ and $y=a-bz$. On the second, these are the same except that we have exchanged the axes.

[image]

If $b>0$ we therefore get
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{a-bR}\mathrm e^{-y^2/2}\mathrm dy\int_{\frac{a-y}b}^\infty \mathrm e^{-z}\mathrm dz
  +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{a-bR}^\infty \mathrm e^{-y^2/2}\mathrm dy\int_R^\infty\mathrm e^{-z}\mathrm dz.$$
This easily becomes
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{a-bR}\mathrm e^{-y^2/2}
\mathrm e^{(y-a)/b}\mathrm dy+Q(a-bR)\mathrm e^{-R}$$
and finally
$$I=Q\left(bR-a+\frac1b\right)\mathrm e^{\frac{1}{2b^2}-\frac ab}+Q(a-bR)\mathrm e^{-R}.$$

Comment: not sure I understand how the integration rigin has divided into 2 parts

Comment: its OK to assume b > 0

Comment: It's broken into two parts because the right-hand figure shows that the lower bound for $z$ is either a function of $y$ for $y<a-bR$ (it's equal to $(a-y)/b$) and for $y>a+bR$ the lower bound for $z$ is constant and equal to $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the Gauss' integral is
$$G:=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathrm{e}^{-y^2/2}\mathrm{d}y=\sqrt{2\pi}$$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).
So we have $Q\leq G/\sqrt{2\pi}=1$ (because we increase the domain of integration and the integrand is non-negative) and then
\begin{align}
\int_{R}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{a-bz}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-y^2/2}\mathrm{d}y\right)\mathrm{e}^{-z}\mathrm{d}z & = \int_{R}^{+\infty}Q(ax-z)\mathrm{e}^{-z}\mathrm{d}z \\
& \leq \int_{R}^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-z}\mathrm{d}z \\
& = \mathrm{e}^{-R}.
\end{align}

Comment: Comment : I provided a bound to the integral as asked in the OP. However, the title does not really match with the question...